# Registros com valores próximos

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de uma luz, tenho que fazer uma consulta que me traga registro com valores próximos. Já tentei utilizando SOUNDEX e até o a função foneticalize, mas não obtive sucesso.
Exemplo:
Digamos que o usuário esteja procurando uma medicamento chamado Dorflex, porém ele não lembra o nome exato e acaba escrevendo Corflex. Quando ele fizer a consulta tenho que sugerir para ele o nome correto (Dorflex) e todos os medicamentos que possuem no nome a palavra Dorflex.

Comment: Segue o link do exemplo que utilizei :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Eu escrevi uma função que uso no Oracle. Comparando DORFLEX com CORFLEX a função me diz que são 86% parecidas. Você pode adapta-la para seu sistema.

```
create or replace function grausimilar(str1 in varchar, 
                               str2 in varchar ) 

return number
is
c1 number;
c2 number;
lcs number;
temp number;
i number;
maximo number;
minimo number;
s1 varchar(1024);
s2 varchar(1024);
begin       
  s1 := trim( str1 );
  s2 := trim( str2 ); 

if ( s1 = '' ) then
 begin
   if ( s2 = '' ) then
      return 0;
   else
      return length( s2 );
  end if;
 end;
end if; 

if ( s2 = '' ) then
     return length( s1 );
end if;     


maximo := length( s1 );
if ( length( s2 ) >  length( s1 )) then
   maximo := length( s2 );
end if;


c1 := 1;
c2 := 1;
lcs := 0;
temp := 0;

while ((c1 <= length( s1 )) and (c2 <= length(s2))) 
loop
    if ( substr(s1, c1, 1 ) = substr( s2, c2, 1 )) then
        lcs := lcs + 1;
    else 
     begin
        if (c1 < c2) then
             c2 := c1;
        else 
            c1 := c2;
        end if;    
        i := 0;
        while ( i < maximo )
        loop    
            if ( (c1 + i < length(s1)) and ( substr( s1, c1 + i, 1 ) =   substr( s2, c2, 1 ))) then 
               begin
                c1 := c1 + i;
                exit;
              end;
            end if;  
            if ((c2 + i < length(s2)) and (substr( s1, c1, 1 ) = substr( s2, c2 + i, 1 ))) then
              begin
                c2 := c2 + i;
                exit;
              end;  
            end if;
            i := i + 1;
        end loop;
      end;
    end if;  
    c1 := c1 + 1;
    c2 := c2 + 1;
end loop;

return round( ((( lcs * 2 ) / (length(s1) + length(s2))) * 100 ));
end;
```